# Get ids of a has_many association ignore includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2.21 application, I have those simple classes :

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope -> do
    where("country_translations.locale = ?", I18n.locale).
      order("country_translations.name").includes(:translations)
  end

  has_many :regions
  has_many :cities
  has_many :translations

  attr_accessible :name, :city_ids
  active_admin_translates :name
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope -> do
    where("region_translations.locale = ?", I18n.locale).
      order("region_translations.name").includes(:translations)
  end

  belongs_to :country
  has_many :cities

  attr_accessible :country, :name, :country_id, :city_ids
  active_admin_translates :name
end
```

When I do `Country.first.region_ids`, I have this error :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "region_translations"
LINE 1: ...regions"  WHERE "regions"."country_id" = 602 AND (region_tra...
                                                         ^
: SELECT "regions".id FROM "regions"  WHERE "regions"."country_id" = 602 AND (region_translations.locale = 'en') ORDER BY region_translations.name
from /home/dougui/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `exec'
```

As you can see, in there SQL request, `region_translations` seems to not be included. Because of that, it can't find it in the order clause. It seems to ignore the inclusion.

`Country.first.regions.map(&:id)` works but it is a uggly hack.

Do you have a better solution?

Comment: How about this one? `Country.joins(:regions).where(id: country_id).pluck('regions.id')`

Comment: Same error. It's preferable to use `region_ids` because of this line : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1143 .

Comment: I think I misread your question at first. I guses the problem is with the `includes` clause. Try changing it to `joins` clause. Maybe this one works.

Comment: joins works but there is on request per region when I do `Region.all.map(&:name)`. The request SELECT "region_translations".* FROM "region_translations" WHERE "region_translations"."region_id" = 13 is executed each time. This is a performence issue.

Comment: How about doing both ways i.e. use `includes` alongside `joins`. Sounds weird though.

Comment: It seems to work. Propose this as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use both `joins` and `includes` in conjunction. This will handle the performance as well as the error.